# Export Firebase Events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a project in firebase who has a lot of events and firebase UI is very bad to see all them so I would like to develop a SPA to have more info about my events.

I need to extract the events from firebase to import in this SPA. Firebase provides a CSV of the events, but this CSV doesn't have the events parameters.

I saw that old firebase used to have a rest api: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html
But I can find the documentation about this rest api in the firebase or any other info about extracting that from firebase.

So, my question is, someone knows any way to extract the events from firebase alongside with the event's parameters?

Comment: I don't think it is accurate for @doug-stevenson to mark this question as duplicate. He is asking how to export raw events from firebase-analytics, not the aggregated results, which is what the other question answered

Comment: @GordonSun as described in the duplicate, export to BigQuery gives you access to all the raw events.

Comment: @DougStevenson the answer in the duplicate don't make it clear that in the BigQuery you have access to all raw events, but it is good to know, I will give it a try. Thanks.